# Java regular expression for negative numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I have this pattern:

`Pattern.compile("T([0-9]*)");`

which works fine for positive numbers but I need it to also do negative numbers for instance "T-1T3T44" should work. Or maybe use space instead of 'T' so it should work for strings like this:"-1 2 3 2 -1 6 2". Sorry I haven't really used regular expressions before.So any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer for space instead of T.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you thought of trying:

```
"T(-?[0-9]+)"
```

You'll notice I've also changed the `"*"` (zero or more) to `"+"` (one or more) since `""` isn't technically a number :-)

Comment: This is not quite correct, as it allows: -0. Zero cannot be negative. To see how to cope with that, see my answer.

Comment: @Fofole: yes, just replace it with a space in the regex, no problems. Lukasz, yes, if you want to disallow negative zero, you'll need something more complex. Personally, I think that's approaching the anal-retentive stage but I see your viewpoint :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is easier to understand and I don't really need to check for -0 as I build the string correctly myself so I flag this as the accepted answer. Hope that everybody is happy about this.

Comment: @paxdiablo well, no, it's not an obsession.. In one of my companies, we were had a very similar issue when we were validating cash amounts with regex pattern that actually WAS allowing sum like -0. This actually brought problems with customers who seemed very irritated with that minus before zero ;-)

Answer (score 11):

```
Pattern.compile("T(-{0,1}(?!0)\\d+)");
```

Please note the usage of negative look-ahead `(?!0)` to exclude -0 number and numbers that start with 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
Pattern.compile("T(-?[0-9]*)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("T-?([0-9]*)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the minus optional may be?

T-?([0-9]*)